# Azure Communication Service - unable to run the quickstart app in Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, azure-communication-services

I'm currently working on setting up a ReactJs app and deploying it into Azure App Service. I followed the instructions provided in the below github url

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-tutorial

It's working fine locally. However, when I deploy it into Azure App Service (https://webcallingappnode.azurewebsites.net/), it fails with a 404 error as shown below.

[image]

in the github url, under **Code Structure** section, as shown below it  says it uses a simple local server for token provisioning.

> ./webpack.config.js: Project bundler. Has a simple local server for
> user token provisioning.

Does it mean it doesn't work after deployment to Production? If not, then how do I get it work?

Comment: Thanks! Could you please confirm if you prepared web app for azure communication services, Check this document link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/tutorials/building-app-start

Comment: No. Haven't done that. Will do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, the sample you're using requires a backend service that is implemented to only work locally. You will need to implement the method to fetch a token.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Was just wondering how provisionUser endpoint is working in local. Any pointers in understanding  that?